# How to save another user in your contacts django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have model of IndividualUser which has OneToOneField to user like its his profile

I'm looking for way to save another user in this model like contacts in your mobile phone

I want to do this with django-rest-framework

I think we can use m2m field there but i dont think that this is good practice for that

So any tips how can i solve that problem?

models.py

```
class IndividualUser(models.Model):
    individual_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=150)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
class IndividualUser(models.Model):
    individual_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=150)

    # question solving line with adjustments thanks 
    # to @Zesshi
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(
            "self", 
            related_name="contact_book", 
            blank=True, 
            symmetrical=False
        )
```

`"self"` as a parameter to `ManyToManyField` tells django that you want to connect that model (`IndividualUser`) with multiple instances of itself. You have to specify a `related_name` in this case because otherwise the functionality of reverse lookups would break.

Ask yourself:

1. Does one User have multiple contacts? Yes.
2. Is that one User on the other hand stored by multiple other Users as a contact? Yes.

Two times yes --> `ManyToMany` 
One time yes --> `ForeignKey`

Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: I would add some details about that for another users: you need actually change related_name on something else and add symetrical = False
```contacts = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="contact_book", blank=True, symmetrical=False)```